# How ClickFunnels handle querystring parameters?

Tags: javascript, php

I am not sure how CF handles querystring parameters, i want to store the data in querystring in contact data and forward that via webhook, is it possible?  CF support did not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

To test your webhooks, set up a https://requestb.in/ and then opt in on your ClickFunnels page or process a test transaction.

You will be able to see exactly how the querystring is set up.